# Linux: How to cat stdout of a process until the end, but stop and return a non-zero code if certain string appears?

Tags: linux, automated-tests, text-processing, fail-fast

We have a tool that runs tests, but does return an error code if they fail.
The tool runs the tests after starting logging in through SSH to a custom console (not bash) and issuing a command. All tests run at once within that invocation
The logging of the tests goes to a file.
The output of the tool is roughly:

```
test1 [ok]
test2 Some message based on the failure
...
```

To stop the build, we need to look for certain strings in the output.
The output appears as the tests run.

I could capture the whole output into a file and fail at the end. But it would save quite some time to fail once the first test fails.

Therefore, I would like something like `tee`, but it would also kill the execution if it finds that failure string. Or, at least, it should print the output as it comes, and return non-zero if a string is found.

Is this doable with the standard Linux toolkit?

Comment: You have been fairly vague about the details. Do the individual tests return error code, if so then why not have the framework stop at the first non-zero error code? If not, then the framework could do the output checking before continuing with the following test.

Comment: Edited. The individual tests to not return anyhing, they run within JVM. But from the perspective of those who start it, it doesn't matter. And yes, the framework could do a lot of things, but it's a bit hard to persuade the author of it to change/implement it... That's why I am looking for this not-so-ellegant solution

Comment: [This answer](https://superuser.com/questions/270529/monitoring-a-file-until-a-string-is-found) seems to provide what you need.

Comment: You can simply read the the output line by line, look for the error message pattern and stop reading when the string appears -- that should interrupt the writing process. I see two potential problems: (1) The test's output may be buffered so that 4k text are output before the read sees it -- try [unbuffer](https://linux.die.net/man/1/unbuffer). (2) the JVM may notice even later that the pipe is broken. You can perhaps capture the JVM's PID and kill it explicitly.

Comment: Use tee for your log file and a script that uses grep to detect the string.  Any output from grep should kill the PID of the top-level process.  That could be done by a python script that is waiting for any line on stdin.

Answer (score 0):

The only solution I can think of is:

1. Start you *build* process and `cat` its output to an output file.
2. Start another script that monitors this file: a loop which iterates every X seconds in search for your, lets say, *forbidden* words in the file. As soon as they appear, kill the *build* process (you may need a way to identify your build process, such as a pid file or something like this) and clear the file.

You can even put this 2 processes in a single shellscript and make them both start and stop when needed.